# Salesforce API via the Python beatbox module

Tags: soap-api, describesobject

I am new to accessing Salesforce data via the API. I am using the beatbox library for Python.

My code:

```
import beatbox

sf = beatbox.PythonClient()
sf.login('my user name', 'my password + security token')

a = sf.describeSObjects('account')
account = a[0]
accountFields = account.fields

for i in accountFields:
    print i
```

This gives me a nice list of the fields in Account object. I cannot figure out how to look up the **data type for each field**, however. I've tried many different iterations based on the examples in the Salesforce API documentation, but not having any luck.

For example, in this code:

```
for i in accountFields:
    print i.type
```

my iterations result in the Python string representation of the field, as opposed to Field object of the describeSObjectresult.

Answer (score 3):

In beatbox, sObject.fields is a python `dict` containing Field objects.  Your existing command is only getting the keys of the dict, which is the field name.  Try this:

```
# the syntax is `for key, value in dict.items()`
for fieldname, fieldspec in account.fields.items():
    print("Type of", fieldname, "is: ", fieldspec.type)     # Python 3.x syntax
```

You can see a list of the field data supported by beatbox by looking at the [source code](https://code.google.com/p/salesforce-beatbox/source/browse/trunk/src/beatbox/python_client.py#447).

Comment: That `print` syntax also works in Python 2.7